# TikZ: Intersection of two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

what is the easiest way to determine the intersection of two lines? I tried

```
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={black,above right}]
\draw[name path=line 1] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[name path=line 2] (2,0) -- (0,2);
\fill[red,name intersections={of=line 1 and line 2}]
    (intersection-1) circle (2pt) node {1}
    (intersection-2) circle (2pt) node {2}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like it's the result of your code.  And that code looks pretty easy to me, what would you like improved?

Comment: Although, this question is quite old, let me ask you for some clarification: What do you understand under “line”? Your question and all answers only use two straight lines. For these you can use `(intersection of c1--c2 and c3--c4)`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The reason the code does not work as provided is that there is only one intersection, and so `(intersection-2)` does not exist.  One way to alleviate this kind of issue is to specify `total=\t` to contain the total number of intersections and the use a `foreach` to loop through each intersection:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={black,above right}]
\draw[name path=line 1] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[name path=line 2] (2,0) -- (0,2);
\fill[red,name intersections={of=line 1 and line 2,total=\t}]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(intersection-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 43):

Reading the [PGF Manual](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/pgfmanual.pdf) helps ;). See page 54ff, I made this from it:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,3);
\draw [name path=A--B] (A) -- (B);
\coordinate (C) at (3,0);
\coordinate (D) at (0,1);
\draw [name path=C--D] (C) -- (D);
\path [name intersections={of=A--B and C--D,by=E}];
\node [fill=red,inner sep=1pt,label=-90:$E$] at (E) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

An alternative, in the form of `tkz-euclide`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}  \tkzDefPoint(2,2){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,2){C}  \tkzDefPoint(2,0){D}
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,B C,D)
  \tkzInterLL(A,B)(C,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
  \tkzDrawPoints(E) \tkzLabelPoints[below](E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first three lines define the points and draw the line segments between them. `\tkzInterLL` compute the intersection of the lines `A--B` and `C--D`, while `\tkzGetPoint{E}` gives the point a name. Finally the point is drawn and labeled.

You can mix this with "normal" TikZ code if you want to, e.g. (borrowing from Tom Bombadil):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,3);
\coordinate (C) at (3,0);
\coordinate (D) at (0,1);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (C) -- (D);
  \tkzInterLL(A,B)(C,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\node [fill=red,inner sep=1pt,label=-90:$E$] at (E) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This only uses `tkz-euclide` to find and name the intersection.

Answer (score 13):

For the intersection of two segments, we don't need the `intersections` library. We can use directly in tikz points like `(intersection of  A--B and C--D)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(A) -- (2,2) coordinate (B);
    \draw (2,0) coordinate(C) -- (0,2) coordinate (D);
    \node[red,scale=3] at (intersection of  A--B and C--D){.};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** I don't think that this syntax is in the manual (of v3.0) ?

**Edit:** It looks like that this syntax is [deprecated now](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/c1e51497546e4eec1b2bda9ddbfa52a3322473c5/tree/doc/generic/pgf/text-en/pgfmanual-en-tikz-coordinates.tex#l468) :(

Comment: this syntax is not described in tikz & pgf manual, v 3.0.1a.

Comment: @Zarko But it still works on version 3.0.1.a Which is very practical because it allows to solve a system of 2 equations to 2 unknown and thus to find the intersection of 2 straight lines whose intersection is not visible.

Comment: @AndréC, i didn'r say, that it not works :-), only that it is not described in recent official `tikz` version.

Comment: @Zarko Certainly, I had asked the team to add the documentation here https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/108/

Comment: @AndréC, good news! now i hope that the new official `tikz` version will be realised soon :-)!

Comment: @AndréC Looks like it [won't be restored](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/632).

Comment: @Alan Yes, it's sad.