# Angle arc size is not perfect

Tags: tikz-pgf

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\coordinate[label = above left:$A$] (A) at (130:3);
\coordinate[label = above right:$D$] (D) at (58:3);
\coordinate[label = above :$E$] (E) at (98:1.8);
\coordinate[label = right:$C$] (C) at (0:3);
\coordinate[label = left:$B$] (B) at (180:3);
\draw (B) -- (D) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (A) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (C);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.60cm,%
opacity=.9](B,E,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.9](B,E,C){$120^{\circ}$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9cm,%
opacity=.9](D,C,E)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1.3](D,C,E){$20^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Question: I want to adjust the arc length of angles 120 and 20. I mean arc of 120 is slightly big while the arc of angle 20 is slightly short.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `\tkzMarkAngle(B,E,C)` and `\tkzMarkAngle(D,C,E)` weren't giving you the correct output was because `E` wasn't actually being defined as the true intersection point of `AC` and `BD`.

Using [this `tkz-euclide` answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31402/128068) from [TikZ: Intersection of two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31398/tikz-intersection-of-two-lines) you can calculate and label the true intersection point `E` using

```
\tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](E)
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \draw (O) circle (3);
    \coordinate[label = above left:$A$] (A) at (130:3);
    \coordinate[label = above right:$D$] (D) at (58:3);
    %\coordinate[label = above :$E$] (E) at (98:1.8);
    \coordinate[label = right:$C$] (C) at (0:3);
    \coordinate[label = left:$B$] (B) at (180:3);
    \draw (B) -- (D) -- (C);
    \draw (B) -- (A) -- (C);
    \draw (B) -- (C);

    \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](E)

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.60cm,%
    opacity=.9](B,E,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.9](B,E,C){$120^{\circ}$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9cm,%
    opacity=.9](D,C,E)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1.3](D,C,E){$20^{\circ}$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```